# How to perform a LEFT JOIN on 2 related tables

Tags: java, hibernate, left-join

So I have 2 tables. A users table and a finished_exams table. The finished_exams table has a user_id as foreign key and is related as OneToOne with the users table.

I made the relation in Users model like this:

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "user")
private FinishedExam finishedExam;
```

And in the FinishedExams model like this:

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private User user;
```

When I call all finished exams like this in the controller:

```
@GetMapping("/all")
public Iterable<FinishedExam> getAllFinishedExams()
{
    return finishedExamRepository.findAll();
}
```

I get all Finishedexams linked with the users which is good.

My question is, is it possible to get ALL users with their finishedExam if they have it and without if they don't (So basically a `LEFT JOIN`)

Is this possible in Hibernate?

EDIT:

I just tried this but it only returns all users without the exams.

```
@GetMapping("/allUsersWithExams")
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
public Iterable<User> getAllUsersWithTheirExams()
{
    return userRepository.findAll();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all sure is possible, you just have to write the query yourself:

```
"Select u from Users u LEFT JOIN u.finishedExam"
```

simple enough.

But what's stopping you to just select all user and get all their finished exam?

```
public Iterable<Users> getAllUsers()
{
    return UsersRepository.findAll();
}
```

It will give you a list of all `Users` independently from having or not any `finishedExam`

Comment: I've seen the query solution which I was hoping to avoid I would rather do it the latter way which looks cleaner in my opinion. But the latter won't get the finishedExams along with the users right? It just gets all users.

Comment: No hibernate does the work of retrieving the association automatically.
With eager fetching it will load it right away, with lazy it will do so when you access the field. There are 4 different way that hibernate uses to retrieve relationship: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch20.html#performance-fetching
And you can change the default by using e.g.@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I just tried that but I only get all the users and not their exams. I have added what I did to my question.

Comment: You mean that all the users have field finishedExam as null?

Comment: No they don't have the finishedExam at all

Comment: Even when I try the query `SELECT u FROM User u LEFT JOIN FinishedExam f ON u.id = f.exam` instead it only returns all users with no exams.

Comment: The reason this didn't work for me was that I didn't have the finishedExam getters and setters inside the User Entity